# JQuery Load rendering content before callback function

Tags: jquery

I have to following code in a script

```
$("#rectContent").animate({opacity:0},400, function(){
    $('#rectContent').load('homeContent.html', function(){
    $('#rectContent').animate({opacity:1},400);});
});
```

It's supposed to load some content from `homeContent.html` (including an image) and render them when they are all loaded.

It doesn't work as intended. The content (including image) starts rendering as the browser is downloading it.

If the content is cached, for example, when the browser refreshes, it works correctly!

I read somewhere that by design JQuery Load renders as it receives data, regardless of the callback function, but the JQuery documentation doesn't mention anything about this.

Comment: you could do it with a regular ajax function.

Comment: The load simply downloads and puts the html into your `rectContent` element. That html probably has an `<img>` tag or something of the sort which tells the browser to load that image, this is a separate request/load so does not delay your animation.

Comment: How do you know that? Any source, or any explanation?

Comment: And you're wrong. I tried load('homeContent.html img'), still the same.